# Most efficient way to replace the entire buffer?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, buffers, replace

Currently, I have two similar methods to replace the entire buffer with some other text (say in clipboard).

Method #1:

1. delete all lines: `:%d`.
2. paste text: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> ( or similar: `:put+`).

Method #2:

1. visually select all lines: <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.
2. paste text: <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>.

However I couldn't seem to find an one-command-fire way to do that. The most close one I found is `:change` command. But it doesn't seem to work well with registers. Of course I can create some function and/or map a key to do that. But before I could make all these customizations, I want to make sure:

> Is there some built-in command to replace a range of lines with some other text?
>   Like, you could `:%replace+` to replace the entire buffer with text in clipboard?

Comment: I don't know of anything off the top of my head, but if you do this a lot, why not create a mapping/command?

Comment: @MattBoehm yeah, as I said, I just want to make sure there _really_ isn't something I missed out. I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hmm, `1,$s/\_./\=@+` is not a solution :P, `:%d|put+` is closer, but not quite there.

Comment: @Sukminder well, I actually like it. :-D Let me try to understand these patterns.

Comment: I forgot an asterisk after the dot ... `1,$s/\_.*/\=@+`, where `\_.` matches any character *including* newline.

Comment: Do you _have_ to reuse the buffer, or would it be acceptable to start a new buffer?

Comment: I think Sukminder's `:%d|put+` fits the bill. It's short and memorable. The other command is just too arcane to remember and type correctly.

Comment: @200_success both are fine to me. I'd like to know alternatives.

Comment: If you are using **MacVim** then you can hit `Cmd-A` to select all the text, then `Cmd-V` to paste over it. The same might work for GVim on **Windows**, using `Ctrl` instead of `Cmd`.

Comment: @joeytwiddle Why not add that as an answer?

Comment: @Sukminder Why not add that as an answer?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: Because of "but not quite there", which was due to it adding a *new line* above paste ...

Answer (score 2):

You could do `ggvG<CTRL-G>` to visually select the whole buffer and enter `Select-mode`. This is the easiest way to replace the buffer with text you're planning on typing out. You may even be able to make a `Select-mode` mapping with `:smap` that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One way to replace the whole buffer with your clipboard can be via external command, for example:

```
:%!pbpaste
:%!echo my_text
```

<sup>See also: [Mac OS X clipboard sharing](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing)</sup>

Or by using substitution:

```
:%s/\_.*/\=@+/
:%s/\_.*/my text/
```

Alternatively use `:%d|put+` (as already suggested in the comments).